# jQuery replace content in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table that is rendered to the page that contains a link to a website. This allows for the user to easily click on it and navigate etc.

I am building a function that I can pass the table to and it will export the data to excel.

The first part of this though is to create a variable of this table data and remove the link from the column leaving it with only the text.

Here is my table:

```
<table id="assignedOpenProjects">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Col 1</th>
        <th>Col 2</th>
        <th>Col 3</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Bob</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td><a href="http://www.google.com">Link</a></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

The 3rd column in the table is the one that contains the link (2nd in terms of 0 based).

My jQuery:

```
// Define the HTML of the table
var table = $('#assignedOpenProjects').prop('outerHTML');

// Loop over all of the table rows
 $(table).find('tbody > tr').each(function () {

    // Loop over the column that contains the link
     $(this).children("td").eq(2).each(function () {

         // Define the value of that column
         var col = $(this).html();

         // Replace the value with the text version
         $(col).replaceWith($(col).text());

     });

});
// Output the table
$('#output').empty().append(table);
```

When I run this, the content is identical and it doesn't remove the link. However if I log the `$(col).text()` to the console, it shows what I am expecting the column to be replace with.

Can some one tell me what I am doing wrong as to why this content is not being replaced as I would expect?

The expected outcome should just contain the word `Link` in Col3 once in the output.

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zrpe8c3x/2/

Comment: The code you have seems to be working in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/veff4k4x/) so are you sure your function is getting hit and not squashed by some other code?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning - The fiddle you provided didn't work for me, even when I selected to use the jQuery library it didn't remove the link from the text.

Answer (score 3):

The approach you're taking of retrieving the HTML of the table and hacking it around is massively overcomplicated. From your description, all you're trying to do is remove the link functionality from the `a` elements, but keep the text. If this is the case, you can make it a simple one-liner using `unwrap()`:

```
$('#assignedOpenProjects').find('a').contents().unwrap();
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/zrpe8c3x/3/)

Comment: While this answer is simple and will probably be the one I select, the reason I had it set up in my demo is because I don't want to alter the table that was rendered to the page. Not only that but there will be some other elements I replace such as `<br />` tags and was trying to determine why it wasn't replacing the table content in the loop. This certainly solves the problem for the OP but I am still curious why the replacement didn't work in the loop.

Comment: Why do you not want to 'alter the table that was rendered to the page'? Surely that's the point of your code...? You can remove the `<br />` tags simply by selecting them and using `remove()`: `$('br').remove()` - obviously your selector would need to be more specific than that to target only those you require.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not working because you initialize your `table` variable using the `outerHTML`, but you don't modify it afterwards, so what you're appending at the end of your code is the same variable you defined before, unchanged, which is the same table you had as an input

It happens because you have the following problems in your code:

1. The `table` variable you're appending at the end is the plain `outerHTML` and not the jQuery object you build and traverse
2. You're changing a new `td` object inside, which never gets appended back to the original `td`, so you end up changing something that you don't use

Here is your code with both things corrected:

```
$('[name=clean]').click(function(){

    // Define the HTML of the table
    var table = $('#assignedOpenProjects').prop('outerHTML');

    var table2 = $(table);
    // Loop over all of the table rows
     table2.find('tbody > tr').each(function () {

        // Loop over the column that contains the link
         $(this).children("td").eq(2).each(function () {

             // Define the value of that column
             var col = $(this);

             // Replace the value with the text version
             $(col).replaceWith($(col).text());

         });

    });
    // Output the table
    $('#output').empty().append(table2);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qs3mk7xn/

That being said, I believe you should pay attention to what Rory answered. If you want the same thing he did but in a different table, you could do something like this:

```
$('[name=clean]').click(function(){
    $('#output').empty().append($('#assignedOpenProjects').clone().find('a').contents().unwrap().parents().last());
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qs3mk7xn/1/

Or, more efficiently, something like this:

```
$('[name=clean]').click(function(){
    var clon = $('#assignedOpenProjects').clone();
    clon.find('a').contents().unwrap();
    $('#output').empty().append(clon);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qs3mk7xn/2/

Or, if you want the third `td` only, something like this:

```
$('[name=clean]').click(function(){
    var clon = $('#assignedOpenProjects').clone();
    clon.find('tbody tr td:nth-child(3) a').contents().unwrap();
    $('#output').empty().append(clon);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qs3mk7xn/3/